# Creating a transition matrix for each unique element in a variable

Tags: r, database, matrix, data-manipulation

I am having an issue with creating a transition matrix, below the the dataset that i'm working on,

```
Name     Rating   ID   DATE(YYYYmmdd)   
@0CC        1   71476   20000704    
@0CC        1   71476   20001204    
@0RM        1   73565   20000919    
@0RM        2   49960   20000131    
@0RM        1   44457   20001214    
@0RM        1   59451   20001023    
@0TL        2   73862   20001212    
@0TL        3   19824   20000929    
@0TL        1   70970   20001211    
@0TL        3   48061   20000627          
@0TL        1   48061   20001227    
@1AJ        1   58875   20001214    
@1AJ        3   56014   20001214    
@1AJ        3   47340   20001214    
@1AJ        3   19813   20001214    
@1AL        1   44416   20000517    
@1AL        4   59184   20000801    
@1AL        3   59184   20000413    
@1AL        4   72832   20001127    
@1AL        1   52718   20000621    
@1AL        2   59184   20000707    
@1AL        3   73568   20001130    
@1AL        3   72832   20001211    
@1AL        3   44416   20000303
```

What i want to do is for every unique name, i would like to compare the ID, and if the ID matches, I would then look at the dates, comparing the later date with the previous date, if ratings are similar, i would ignore but if ratings is different i would like to count the number of moves.

E.g in the first two rows, looking at Name @OCC, the ID variable matches and looking at the rating, they are similar then i do not add that to count. However,looking at @1AL, the ID variable matches thrice, looking at the dates that occur, there are three dates 20000413,20000707 and 20000801 with ratings 3,2 and 4 respectively. As ratings changed from 3 to 2 to 4 again, i would like to recorded it in a transition matrix of the following format.

```
 From   1 2 3 4 5 (to)
  1
  2           1 
  3       1
  4
  5
```

Being quite new to this data management thing, this is what i have,

```
for(i in unique(dataset$Name)
if dataset[,3]=dataset[,3]
```

which i don't think that the second line is even right. I am really really stuck and would appreciate any advice that i can get.

Answer (score 1):

It took some time, but I think I figured out one solution for your problem:

**convert into data.table**

```
install.packages("data.table") #if not installed already
require(data.table)
### DT: your data.frame
### e.g. copy and 
#DT <- read.table("clipboard",header = T)
DT <- as.data.table(DT) # convert into data.table
setkey(DT, Name, DATE)
#this shows some temporary result:
DT[, print(Rating), by = list(Name, ID)]
  # [1] 1 1
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 2
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 2
  # [1] 3
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 3 1
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 3
  # [1] 3
  # [1] 3
  # [1] 1 3
  # [1] 4 3 2
  # [1] 4 3
  # [1] 1
  # [1] 3
```

One problem is that data.table does not return a vector for each subset (as far as I know). So the solution is to convert the single digit numbers into a longer number and convert them back later.

**get ratings**

```
setVal <- function(vec){
  res <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(vec)){
    res <- res + vec[i] * 10^(length(vec)-i)
  }
  return(as.integer(res))
}
#save above shown result in vector.
DT <- DT[, R:=setVal(Rating), by = list(Name, ID)]
DT #the result is not as desired because e.g. 324 occurs 3 times (at each row which leads to 324), 11 occurs 2 times (at both rows contributing to 11).
  # Name Rating    ID DATE.YYYYmmdd.   R
  # 1: @0CC      1 71476       20000704  11
  # 2: @0CC      1 71476       20001204  11
  # 3: @0RM      2 49960       20000131   2
  # 4: @0RM      1 73565       20000919   1
  # 5: @0RM      1 59451       20001023   1
  # 6: @0RM      1 44457       20001214   1
  # 7: @0TL      3 48061       20000627  31
  # 8: @0TL      3 19824       20000929   3
  # 9: @0TL      1 70970       20001211   1
  # 10: @0TL      2 73862       20001212   2
  # 11: @0TL      1 48061       20001227  31
  # 12: @1AJ      1 58875       20001214   1
  # 13: @1AJ      3 56014       20001214   3
  # 14: @1AJ      3 47340       20001214   3
  # 15: @1AJ      3 19813       20001214   3
  # 16: @1AL      3 44416       20000303  31
  # 17: @1AL      3 59184       20000413 324
  # 18: @1AL      1 44416       20000517  31
  # 19: @1AL      1 52718       20000621   1
  # 20: @1AL      2 59184       20000707 324
  # 21: @1AL      4 59184       20000801 324
  # 22: @1AL      4 72832       20001127  43
  # 23: @1AL      3 73568       20001130   3
  # 24: @1AL      3 72832       20001211  43
#The result has to be filtered by unique pairs of Name and ID.
R <- DT[,unique(R), by = list(Name, ID)]$V1
#[1]  11   2   1   1   1  31   3   1   2   1   3   3   3  31 324   1  43   3
```

**transform result into transition matrix**

Probably there is some easier way to convert `R` back into single digits, count the values and put them into a matrix, but this is what I thought of:

```
TransitionMatrix <- function(col, ncol = 5){
  intoMat <- function(Mat, vec){
    if(length(vec)>1){
      for (i in 1:(length(vec)-1)){
        if (vec[i] != vec[i+1]){
          Mat[vec[i], vec[i+1]] <- Mat[vec[i], vec[i+1]] + 1
        }
      }
    }
    return(Mat)
  }
  Mat <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol, nrow = ncol)
  for (j in 1:length(col)){
    L <- nchar(as.character(j))
    if(L>1){
      values <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(col[j]),"")))
      Mat <- intoMat(Mat, values)
    }
  }
  return(Mat)
}

TransitionMatrix(R, 5)
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  # [1,]    0    0    2    0    0
  # [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
  # [3,]    2    3    0    0    0
  # [4,]    0    0    5    0    0
  # [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

A limitation of this solution is when the ratings get higher than 9 and have 2 digits.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the solution, i appreciate it. Firstly, i have added a setkey to rearrange the table according to dates which reaarranges the datatable according to dates. something is cropping up on my comments which prevents me from putting up my code in the comment section which is annoying, i've added it in by editing the solution that you provide, hope that you don't mind. I really don't get what is happening in the get ratings section of the code if you can further explain that to me? however, there seems to be a double counting, the soln isn't correct.

Comment: Yup it does gives the desired results. However, the issue now is to convert that into a vector that is usable as mentioned which i'm stucked. @Phann

Comment: For code in comments insert it between [double backticks]code[double backticks]. With the *get ratings* part I wanted to save the output of each subset into one (integer) variable as I don't know of a way to return a vector for each subset. So what I actually want is some *object* containing what can be seen with ``print``. The workaround here is to save the single digit numbers in one integer number where each digits of this integer is one element of this *subset vector*.

Comment: This was the modification that i made which works and provide the right results ``#DT <- read.table("clipboard",header = T)
DT <- as.data.table(DT) # convert into data.table
setkey(DT, Name, DATE)``

Comment: I can see where the error is coming from by doing the second step ``setVal <- function(vec){
  res <- 0
  for (i in !:length(vec)){
    res <- res + vec[i] * 10^(length(vec)-i)
  }
  return(as.integer(res))
}
#save above shown result in vector.
R <- DT[, R:=setVal(Rating), by = list(Name, ID)]$R
#[1]  11  11   1   2   1   1   2   3   1  31  31   1   3   3   3
#[16]  13 432 432  43   1 432   3  43  13`` a new variable called R is created which results in the double and triple counting. e.g 11 for @OCC is counted twice. @Phann

Comment: At least the for loop should be from ``1:length(vec)``, I correct that..

Comment: I found the problem with multiple occurences. It can be seen with ``DT[, R:=setVal(Rating), by = list(Name, ID)]``, ``DT``. E.g. 432 occurs in each line of the data.table with the same Name and ID. So it has to be filtered for unique pairs of these values. ``DT[,unique(R), by = list(Name, ID)]`` gives the correct result then.